# Verb and noun in plural

Tags: verb-agreement

What do I call people who eat donuts?

**donuts** eaters
or
**donut** eaters

Comment: There are exceptions (eg singles bar; systems analyst; travellers cheque; dogs home; working mens club [yes, usually without apostrophes]), but most nouns when used attributively are in the singular form. This 'rule' is not inviolate; a minority of examples of 'donuts eaters' _can_ be found on the internet.

Comment: Nobody says *I eat **cornflake***, but there are far more written instances of singular [***cornflake** eaters*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cornflake+eaters%22) in Google Books than there are of plural [***cornflakes** eaters*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22cornflakes+eaters%22)

Comment: Thank you for your comments!